# Typescript codebase failing after reinstalling node and npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, macos, npm

I have reinstalled node and npm after that my `Typescript` React Project is failing with the following error-

```
    Argument of type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
  Type 'unknown[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>': type, props, key  TS2345
```

code for this -

```
    import * as renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

    let instance;
    const wrapper = shallow(
    <SomeComponent
    updateOptions={null}
    someProps={"val"}
    />,
    );

    instance = wrapper.instance();

    const result = instance.renderOperands();
    expect(Object.values(result).length).toEqual(instance.currentOperandCount);
    const tree = renderer.create(Object.values(result)).toJSON();
```

My configuration -

```
    OS- MacOS Mojave (10.14.6)
    Node - v12.12.0
    npm - 6.11.3
```

Attached [Package.json](https://gist.github.com/sandipp/1b87dcdf2f5b2614ba83645682753891)

Typescript Configs -

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/libs/*.js"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

TS Lint Config-

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "no-console": false,
    "no-bitwise": false,
    "only-arrow-functions": false,
    "no-debugger": false,
    "jsx-no-lambda": false
  },
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "config/**/*.js",
      "docs/**/*.js",
      "node_modules/**/*.ts"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have upgraded node from 10.10.0 to 12.12.0 and even after going back to older version of node it's still failing. 
I am sure about completely uninstalling and reinstalling node correctly.

Comment: @keikai added the code

Comment: clean global module and install it all again.
`rm -rf ~/.npm
rm -rf node_modules
npm clean cache --force`